# Getting a RadioButton's value

Tags: java, android

How can I get the values of my simple radio button quiz to a new XML layout page. I'm not sure what happened. When i click on the button, it force closes.

```
TextView hasil;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            int score = 0;
            if (((RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton1)).isChecked()) {score++;}
            if (((RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton8)).isChecked()) {score++;}
            if (((RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton11)).isChecked()) {score++;}
            if (((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton16)).isChecked()){score++;}
            if (((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton19)).isChecked()){score++;}
            if (((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton24)).isChecked()){score++;}
            if (((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton25)).isChecked()){score++;}
            if (((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton29)).isChecked()){score++;}

            displayResult(score);
        }

    });
}

private void displayResult(int score) {
    String message = "You scored " + score;
    message += " out of 6";
    message += "\nWell done!";
    hasil.setText(message);
}
```

Comment: please post the logcat at the time of crash

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have initialized hasil TextView. 
Add the following line in OnCreate method, by replacing HASIL_ID with the  appropriate ID.

```
hasil = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.HASIL_ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add logcat message so that one can know what's caused your app to crash.

However if you want to know which radio button is checked, you can try the code below.

```
int score=0;
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_RADIO_GROUP_ID);
switch (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
                case R.id.radioButton1:
                    score++;
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButton8:
                    score++;
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButton11:
                    score++;
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButton16:
                    score++;
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButton19:
                    score++;
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButton24:
                    score++;
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButton25:
                    score++;
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButton29:
                    score++;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
```

I assume you have placed your radio buttons inside radio group.